# German 'Umlaut's in R package description

Tags: r, string, package, rstudio, roxygen2

I wrote a function in R that replaces german letters like ä, ö, ü and ß and want to document it in my package. My example is:

```
#' @examples "Aber das ist es nun mal, was wir tun: wir träumen weiter gegen 
#' den Strom und unsere Träume entschlüpfen uns fast so lebendig, wie wir sie
#' heraufbeschwören können." %>% replace_german_letters
```

When I build the package instead of the 'Umlauts' something like "Ã¤" is shown.
My encoding setting is already UTF-8 in RStudio. I am using roxygen2 to build my package.

Comment: I feel you. I have the same problems with ščž.

Comment: Not sure if this is the same kind of "problem" but when i got a RStudio script with umlauts, i need to Reopen with encoding most of the times to get them right.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik and OP: Check [this roxygen github issue](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/613) and [this discussion](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1421) in r-lib/devtools. Basicly you need to encode non-ascii characters in the `\uxxxx` form. Not sure it this will work in your code example, but seems to work for some people.

Comment: @phiver: Does not work for me. But I'm not sure if I did it right. How would you concretely replace i.e. "träumen" in the example?

Comment: `x <- "tr\U00E4umen"; print(x)` prints `"träumen"`

Comment: @MauritsEvers But I have to print it in the examples of my package description. A command does not work here.

Comment: @TonySunshine I understand that; what happens if you replace `"träumen"` with `"tr\U00E4umen"` in your roxygen comment?

Comment: Then it prints "tr\U00E4umen" :(

Comment: @TonySunshine Hmm, not sure then, sorry. PS. Just to exhaust this avenue: `"tr\u00e4umen"` (with lower caps "u") does also not work?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.